# ViewPager Fragment Views retaining values from previous state

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a 3-tab ViewPager with custom Fragments (EntryFragment and CalendarFragment; the third is not relevant to the question). Now when I click a date on CalendarFragment the EntryFragment should load up with data of the new date (I have coded it this way).

Now, what happens is something strange: The TextFields in EntryFragment get changed to the new data from the new date. But the Seekbars, Spinners, Switches, etc retain data from their previous date.

I am using the following methods to set the values of the various Views:

```
seekbar.setProgress(int);
spinner.setSelection(int, false);
switch.setChecked(boolean);
```

Also, I have attached onItemSelectedListerners for these components. These are getting called automatically after onCreateView() of EntryFragment.

Could anyone guide me why this is happening? Or how to prevent it?

Comment: post the class where you have those items you want to update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing it might be restoring previous state, ViewPagers have inbuilt mechanism to restore views that had been hidden. Your data is set to correct values and restored to previous state after that. To prevent that, try to add saveEnabled=false in xml layout of views you are having problem with.